# Border length of child div have width same parent div?

Tags: html, css

I want to add a `border-bottom` between to `post`. But my post created by featured image and except `wrap` by parent `div`.

Like this:

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 48px;
}
.thumbnail {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.except {
    margin-left: 350px;
    min-height: 235px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="thumbnail">
          <img width="324" height="212" src="https://sharengay.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/banner-thu-thuat-xem-phim-netflix-324x212.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="except">
          <span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="thumbnail">
          <img width="324" height="212" src="https://sharengay.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/banner-thu-thuat-xem-phim-netflix-324x212.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="except">
          <span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

By some reason, I must add `border-bottom` in class `except` but it only draw a line for this element. I want to the property `border-bottom` is full in element `wrapper`.

You can test on production website at here: https://sharengay.com

You can see currently like this:

[image]

Comment: you could just have the border be on the bottom of the wrapper?

Comment: @Jhecht yes, I was tried. But you can go to my blog: https://sharengay.com
You can test this. I don't have any method to create like `<hr>` between to post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap it in a div

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 48px;
}
.thumbnail {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.except {
    margin-left: 350px;
    min-height: 235px;

}
.subwrapper { /* Target */
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="subwrapper">
    <div class="thumbnail">
          <img width="324" height="212" src="https://sharengay.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/banner-thu-thuat-xem-phim-netflix-324x212.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="except">
          <span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="thumbnail">
          <img width="324" height="212" src="https://sharengay.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/banner-thu-thuat-xem-phim-netflix-324x212.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="except">
          <span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mpunwb

Comment: Thanks, man, it's a solution. But I add custom your class, I must edit my theme. I using WordPress.

Comment: My pleasure. You will need to create a child-theme and make edits in there so it will persist after theme updates.

Comment: But this element base on the core of Newspaper theme. Have any method to edit it? I also have a child theme.

Comment: Child-themes just overwrite the main theme at runtime so if you make edits, the will persist after the parent theme is updated. In your theme folder, find the code that is responsible for this component, then create a file in the child-theme folder (if it doesn't already exist) that resides in the same location. eg: parent-theme/layout/header.tpl - child-theme/layout/header.tpl
Copy the code in, edit it to include your new div and save

Comment: Your answer more than my question. You're awesome!

Comment: Happy coding, brother

Answer (score 2):

Do I understand correctly : you want border-bottom along the entire length of `wrapper` ?
if so you need to remove `margin-left: 350px;`

```
.except {
    min-height: 235px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
}
```

**Code Snippet:**

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 48px;
}
.thumbnail {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.except {
    min-height: 235px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="thumbnail">
          <img width="324" height="212" src="https://sharengay.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/banner-thu-thuat-xem-phim-netflix-324x212.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="except">
          <span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="thumbnail">
          <img width="324" height="212" src="https://sharengay.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/banner-thu-thuat-xem-phim-netflix-324x212.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="except">
          <span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If remove `margin-left`. It will be lost because of the thumbnail show at this position

Comment: Try to wrap it in another div http://plnkr.co/edit/BCebaHgP3XdlZ8Ytpvlh?p=preview

Comment: @BartoszTermena, that is exactly what [Mark Bell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53248125/9134576) states.

Comment: @DudeCoder Yeah i see now

Comment: Thanks, man, it's a solution. But I add custom your class, I must edit my theme. I using WordPress.